# R Calculate the mean of the following days in time series data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset with three variables: date, signal and value. Now I want to mutate a new colum, which is conditioned of the signals and calculated from the value-column.

If there is a signal on a previous day (`ifelse(lag(signal)==1`), then calculate the mean of the values of the following three days.
In this case I've used this expression:

`(value+lead(value)+lead(value,n = 2)) /3`.

And so I get what I want:

```
set.seed(123)

df<-tibble(date=today()+0:10,
       signal=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),
       value= sample.int(n=11))


df%>%mutate(calculation=ifelse(lag(signal)==1,
                           (value+lead(value)+lead(value, n = 2)) /3,
                           NA))

# A tibble: 11 x 4
   date       signal value calculation
   <date>      <dbl> <int>       <dbl>
 1 2019-07-17      0     1       NA   
 2 2019-07-18      1     7       NA   
 3 2019-07-19      0     5        6.33
 4 2019-07-20      0     4       NA   
 5 2019-07-21      0    10       NA   
 6 2019-07-22      0     2       NA   
 7 2019-07-23      1     9       NA   
 8 2019-07-24      0     3        7.33
 9 2019-07-25      0    11       NA   
10 2019-07-26      0     8       NA   
11 2019-07-27      0     6       NA
```

But my problem is that I do not just want to use the following 3 days.
I want to use several days. And so I want to automate the code and calculate several columns. Maybe with something like an apply-function.

Here is my desired output (in this example with 5 following days):

```
 date       signal value calc_day_1   calc_day2   calc_day3   calc_day4   calc_day5
 <date>      <dbl> <int>       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 2019-07-17      0     1       NA          NA
 2 2019-07-18      1     7       NA          NA
 3 2019-07-19      0     5        5      (5+4)/2=4.5
 4 2019-07-20      0     4       NA          NA
 5 2019-07-21      0    10       NA          NA 
 6 2019-07-22      0     2       NA          NA   
 7 2019-07-23      1     9       NA          NA   
 8 2019-07-24      0     3        3      (3+11)/2=7
 9 2019-07-25      0    11       NA          NA   
10 2019-07-26      0     8       NA          NA   
11 2019-07-27      0     6       NA          NA
```

Can someone show me how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use the `rlang` package and the `purrr` package as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

myfun <- paste0("if_else(lag(signal) == 1, map_dbl(1:n(), ~mean(value[.x - 1 + 1:",
                 1:5 ,"])), NA_real_)") %>%
  setNames(paste0("calc_day", 1:5)) %>% 
  purrr::map(rlang::parse_expr)

df %>% 
  mutate(!!! myfun)

# A tibble: 11 x 8
   date       signal value calc_day1 calc_day2 calc_day3 calc_day4 calc_day5
   <date>      <dbl> <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 2019-07-17      0     3        NA      NA          NA     NA         NA  
 2 2019-07-18      1    11        NA      NA          NA     NA         NA  
 3 2019-07-19      0     2         2       4           6      5.75       5.4
 4 2019-07-20      0     6        NA      NA          NA     NA         NA  
 5 2019-07-21      0    10        NA      NA          NA     NA         NA  
 6 2019-07-22      0     5        NA      NA          NA     NA         NA  
 7 2019-07-23      1     4        NA      NA          NA     NA         NA  
 8 2019-07-24      0     9         9       8.5         6      6.25      NA  
 9 2019-07-25      0     8        NA      NA          NA     NA         NA  
10 2019-07-26      0     1        NA      NA          NA     NA         NA  
11 2019-07-27      0     7        NA      NA          NA     NA         NA
```

Small explanation: if you just wanted one these columns (say `calc_day2`) you could do the following:

```
df %>%
 mutate(calc_day2 = if_else(lag(signal) == 1, map_dbl(1:n(), ~ mean(value[.x - 1 + 1:2])), NA_real_))
```

So in theory you could just copy this line just five times (each time replacing the `2` with the corresponding number).

Or you use the `rlang` package (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56933339/using-quotations-inside-mutate-an-alternative-to-mutate-dots)) to take a shortcut :).

Comment: Yes. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: But why you are using this three exclamation marks in `df %>% 
  mutate(!!! myfun)` ?

Comment: See Konrad Rudolph's answer in the question I linked in my answer.